# VBA Code to change font and size in an email from access

Tags: vba, ms-access, fonts

I have an access form that runs a query. There is a command button on the form that I want to send an email with the query results attached in an excel spreadsheet. Using the code below I am able to attach the results and send the email ok. I would like to be able to format the email body so that it is more noticeable. I'm not really sure how to go about doing this and still have my query attached. I have also created an email template that I would use but I haven't been able to figure out how to use the template and attach the query results. I'm open for any suggestions.  Any help would be greatly appreciated.

```
 DoCmd.SendObject acQuery, "BoxOrder", "ExcelWorkbook(*.xlsx)", "me@home.com", _
     "John@hishome.com", "", "BOX ORDER", _
     "ALL BOXES STITCHED" & vbCrLf & "Questions: Please Call Me" & _
     vbCrLf & "555-555-5555 x 66654", True, True
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could follow the [Article](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/aa167323(v=office.11).aspx) from MS.

A proportion of the code is as follows:

```
Set ola1 = New Outlook.Application

Set mai1 = ola1.CreateItem(olMailItem)
mai1.To = strTo
mai1.Subject = strSubj
If bolHTML = True Then
    mai1.HTMLBody = strBody
Else
    mai1.Body = strBody
End If
mai1.Display
```

If you use the HTML (set bolHTML = True) version you can either have an RTF control on a Form and pass the formatted text over or hardcode your HTML with the formatting you need. Just set the "strBody" to the message you want.

Then you need to look into the Attachments.Add ([MS Article](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff862085.aspx)) if you want to use the above code with your original purpose.

There's a full [599CD Email Seminar](http://599cd.com/site/courselist/seminars/access-email/) you could follow if you're going to be doing a lot with Email in Access.

Comment: Ok.. I will give this a shot. Thank you.

Comment: Another quick question. I just ran into a problem with my one part of my code. I have a command button that when it is pressed it determines what day of the week it is. On a certain day it is supposed to check the status field and for each record that is labeled "Needs Ordered" a query is run and is opened. This works fine unless the last record that was selected is marked different (OK or Ordered). I need it to run no matter how the last record was labeled.

Comment: If Weekday(Now()) = vbSunday Then
    
        If Forms![Admin Box List].Status.Value = "Needs Ordered" Then
            DoCmd.OpenForm "OrderForm"
        End If
    End If

Comment: As its a new question it needs to be created as one, link back to it here.

Comment: sorry about that. I will do that. Thanks.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33066961/vba-code-to-check-the-status-field-of-all-records