# VBA code to check the status field of all records

Tags: ms-access, vba

I just ran into a problem with my one part of my code. I have a command button that when it is pressed it determines what day of the week it is. On a certain day it is supposed to check the status field and for each record that is labeled "Needs Ordered" a query is run and is opened. This works fine unless the last record that was opened is marked different (OK or Ordered). I need it to run no matter how the last record opened was labeled.
[VBA Code to change font and size in an email from access](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33056979/vba-code-to-change-font-and-size-in-an-email-from-access/33061898#33061898)

```
If Weekday(Now()) = vbSunday Then 
    If Forms![Admin Box List].Status.Value = "Needs Ordered" Then 
        DoCmd.OpenForm "OrderForm" 
    End If 
End If
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Then just leave out that condition:

```
Dim rs As DAO.Recordset
If Weekday(Date) = vbSunday Then 
    Set rs = Me.RecordsetClone
    rs.FindFirst "Status = '" & "Needs Ordered" & "'"
    If rs.NoMatch = False Then
        DoCmd.OpenForm "OrderForm" 
    End If
End If 
Set rs = Nothing
```

Comment: And I wondered if it was that simple - watching for a trap. Please mark as answered.

Comment: I just ran into a problem. If I do it this way... when I press the save command button then the orderfom will open and show me all the records that need ordered. However, if none of the records are marked as needs ordered the button still opens the orderform. I only want the orderform to open when there are records that need ordered. I hope that makes sense.

Comment: You could try using the code line I appended above.

Comment: Using the code above gives a runtime error. It says "You entered an expression that has an invalid reference to the Recordset Clone Property"  I don't know much about using recordset much so any help is appreciated.

Comment: If so, your OrderForm hasn't a recordset which seems unlikely except if it is unbound which neither is very likely.

Comment: The order form is actually a query that searches for only "Needs Ordered" criteria on the status field.

Comment: That did it!!! I'm new to doing most of this but this site has helped me a lot with coding problems. Thank you so much Gustav. I really appreciate it.